# Преобразовать многомерный массив в одномерный и получить дочернии категории. PHP

Tags: php, массивы

```
<?php

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Пользователи',
    'alias' => 'users',
    'childrens' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Создание',
        'alias' => 'create',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Список',
        'alias' => 'list',
        'childrens' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 4,
            'name' => 'Активные',
            'alias' => 'active',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 5,
            'name' => 'Удаленные',
            'alias' => 'deleted',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'id' => 8,
        'name' => 'Поиск',
        'alias' => 'search',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6,
    'name' => 'Заявки',
    'alias' => 'requests',
    'childrens' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 9,
        'name' => 'Заявки на поключение',
        'alias' => 'connecting',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Заявки на ремонт',
        'alias' => 'repairs',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'id' => 11,
        'name' => 'Заявки на обход',
        'alias' => 'round',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 7,
    'name' => 'Отчёты',
    'alias' => 'reports',
    'childrens' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 12,
        'name' => 'Отдел маркетинга',
        'alias' => 'marketing',
        'childrens' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 15,
            'name' => 'Отчёт по списаниям',
            'alias' => 'write-offs',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 16,
            'name' => 'Отчёт по расходам',
            'alias' => 'costs',
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'id' => 17,
            'name' => 'Годовой отчёт',
            'alias' => 'year',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 14,
        'name' => 'Управление',
        'alias' => 'control',
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 18,
            'name' => 'Отчёт по эффективности работы',
            'alias' => 'efficiency',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 19,
            'name' => 'Отчёт по подключениям',
            'alias' => 'connecting',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

в одномерный. Вот так пробовал -

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents("categories.json");
$categories = json_decode($json, true);


foreach ($categories as $category) {    //Level 1
    $category_id = $category['id'];
    $category_name = $category['name'];
    $category_alias = $category['alias'];
    $category_child = $category['childrens'];

    foreach ($category_child as $child) {   //Level 2
        $child_new_data = $child['childrens'];
        if ($child_new_data !== NULL) {
            foreach ($child_new_data as $child_new) {   //Level 3

            }
            
        }
        else{
            if ($child[0] !== NULL) {
                foreach ($child[0] as $child_3) {

                };
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

но не могу сообразить что дальше делать... Нужно получить вот такой массив

```
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["name"]=>
  string(24) "Пользователи"
  ["alias"]=>
  string(5) "users"
  ["childrens"]=> "Создание, список, поиск"
}
array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Создание"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(6) "create"
    }
array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(3)
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "Список"
      ["alias"]=>
      string(4) "list"
      ["childrens"]=> "Активные, удаленные"
}
```

для того что бы записать в бд. Тут нужна рекурсия? Не совсем понимаю просто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Пользователи',
    'alias' => 'users',
    'childrens' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Создание',
        'alias' => 'create',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Список',
        'alias' => 'list',
        'childrens' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 4,
            'name' => 'Активные',
            'alias' => 'active',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 5,
            'name' => 'Удаленные',
            'alias' => 'deleted',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'id' => 8,
        'name' => 'Поиск',
        'alias' => 'search',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6,
    'name' => 'Заявки',
    'alias' => 'requests',
    'childrens' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 9,
        'name' => 'Заявки на поключение',
        'alias' => 'connecting',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Заявки на ремонт',
        'alias' => 'repairs',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'id' => 11,
        'name' => 'Заявки на обход',
        'alias' => 'round',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 7,
    'name' => 'Отчёты',
    'alias' => 'reports',
    'childrens' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 12,
        'name' => 'Отдел маркетинга',
        'alias' => 'marketing',
        'childrens' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 15,
            'name' => 'Отчёт по списаниям',
            'alias' => 'write-offs',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 16,
            'name' => 'Отчёт по расходам',
            'alias' => 'costs',
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'id' => 17,
            'name' => 'Годовой отчёт',
            'alias' => 'year',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 14,
        'name' => 'Управление',
        'alias' => 'control',
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 18,
            'name' => 'Отчёт по эффективности работы',
            'alias' => 'efficiency',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 19,
            'name' => 'Отчёт по подключениям',
            'alias' => 'connecting',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

function flatten($arr) 
{
    $ret = [];
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        $tmp = ['id' => $item['id'], 'name' => $item['name'], 'alias' => $item['alias'], ];
        $hasChildren = array_key_exists('childrens', $item);
        if ($hasChildren)  {
            $tmp['childrens'] = array_reduce( 
                $item['childrens'],
                function ($prev, $_item) {return ltrim($prev . ', ' . $_item['name'], ', ');},
                ''
            );
        }
        
        $ret[] = $tmp;
            
        if ($hasChildren) {
            $ret = array_merge($ret, flatten($item['childrens']));
        }
            
    }
    
    return $ret; 
}

var_dump(flatten($arr));
```

[Run code](https://3v4l.org/IHJHe)

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Единственное тут не оказалось "Отчёт по эффективности работы" и "Отчёт по подключениям" возможно из того что они не children а просто как массивы 0 и 1(в самом конце)

Comment: А можно как то модернизировать код что бы добавлять не childrens а parent_id исходя из childrens?

Comment: @razrab345 добавьте функции вторым параметром parentId (nullable) и в рекурсии пробрасывайте его.